How can I automatically duplicate/clone objects during runtime?
I am currently making a "game" application in VB.NET (not the most efficient, I know), and I am having some issues with creating many objects with similar properties automatically. I'm trying to draw many of the same bullets on-screen at once, moving downwards each timer tick, but I simply cannot figure out how to duplicate one PictureBox without making them all manually.
I have the following pseudocode:
On StraightBulletTimer.Tick
     Create Bullet as New PictureBox
     Move all bullets down 3 pixels 
     If any Bullet.Location.Y < 0 Then  ' This line assumes the lower Y-boundary of the form is 0
          Dispose of said bullet
     End If

...But I simply do not know how to implement it. I was considering using two timers; one to create the bullets at a slower interval, and one to move them downwards at a faster interval for the sake of smoothness - but I still don't know how I would create a ton of similar objects and then move all of them at once.
If this helps anyone, the game is a bullet hell, similar to Touhou.
(p.s.: If it's not obvious, I am new to VB.NET and programming in general)

As you can imagine, this has been done before a few times :) A google for "vb.net bullet class" gives things like How do I set my picturebox (bullets in my case) on their own axis separate from my character's movement?, which may contain plenty of information to help you with this. There are even videos on the subject, although I haven't watched any to be able to suggest one.

@AndrewMorton Thanks! I did look it up, but the answers didn't seem related. Checked that post and I instantly got a general idea of what I need to do. Much appreciation :)
